# How to print something to the console on breakpoint?

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, breakpoints, conditional-breakpoint

I'm wondering if there is any option to print something to console on breakpoint. I had an idea to hack conditional breakpoints feature in IntelliJ IDEA.

I wrote such a class:

```
public class BreakpointPrinter {

    public static boolean print(Object object){
        System.out.println(object);
        return false;
    }
}
```

and use it like that:
[image: breakpoint hack]

but unfortunately I get an error: 
[image: breakpoint error]

Do you have any better ideas to achieve such a goal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right click on the breakpoint:

[image]

Click on `More`

[image]

Select `Evaluate and log` and enter the code you want to execute.

In the above example the breakpoint executes `System.out.println("I reached my breakpoint")` and as soon as the breakpoint is reached that string is written to the IntelliJ console.

I suspect the reason you are getting a `ClassNotFoundException` is that your class (`BreakpointPrinter`) is not on the classpath for the JVM instance spawned by IntelliJ. However, if all you want to do is write to console everytime a specific breakpoint is reached then you can do so using a class which is always available in the JVM (e.g. `java.lang.System`) and you can trigger it via the breakpoint's `Evaluate and log` feature.

Comment: Thanks! Helped me a lot. What I really wanted to do was printing something without stopping on breakpoint. This can be achieved by using your approach + unchecking "Suspend" checkbox on breakpoint